# Angular 2 Setup Issue

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am trying to get an angular 2 app working and am having some problems with the upgrade adapter.

Here is my code:

boot.ts

```
/// <reference path="..\..\typings\main.d.ts" />

import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser' 
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);


angular.module('app', []).directive('myApp', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
```

This code is throwing the following exception when I try to compile it with my typescript gulp action.

gulp : src\app\boot.ts(11,46): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp compile-ts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (src\app\boot.ts...f type 'any[]'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Property 'push' is missing in type 'Function'.

Now if I create a directive manually like this in boot.ts, the error doesn't occur.

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('tabsPane', TabsPane);


function TabsPane(itemTabs) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E'
    };


}
```

So obviouslly something is happening in upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent), but I cannot figure out what.

It seems there is just a type issue between downgradeNg2Component returning "any", and directive() expecting a IDirectiveFactory, but this is the exact format from the angular 2 sample, so I don't know what else to try.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Fixed it with the following code.

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('myApp', <angular.IDirectiveFactory>adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) the correct answer to your question would be this one. 
Applies to RC6, 2.0.1 and 2.0.2.

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive(
    'myApp',
    upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent) as    angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );
```

Comment: Aside from how the upgradeAdapter is cast to an IDirectiveFactory, is there any difference between this answer and the answer provided almost 10 months ago by the OP?